# Not using translation from string.xml on older systems

Tags: android, translation

In my app I am using another strings.xml for english translation. The language is changed via:

```
    private void saveLang(String lng) {

    Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    super.recreate();

}
```

The problem I noticed these days, that the english strings file is absolutely ignored on Android 6 and 7, but works fine on Android 8.

So my question is, why the translation is not working on older devices, but works on Android 8 and higher? The screen just reloads, but the text is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented a lot and finally found out, when I replace `getBaseContext().getResources()` with just `this.getResources()` then it started to work on older androids too!

Strange thing, that on Android 8 it works with getBaseContext()